# How to modify output of ping command in terminal using shell?

Tags: shell, ping

The output of a typical ping command is -

```
--- 192.168.1.107 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 1 received, 50% packet loss, time 1008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.288/0.288/0.288/0.000 ms
```

I want to display only "50% packet loss" portion on a terminal window when  I run the ping command in a shell script. How should I proceed for it ?

Comment: `ping -c 2 -q remotehost | sed -n 's/.*received, \([0-9]*%[^,]*\).*/\1/p'` will work but subject to the format of the `ping` output.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using grep

`-o` tells `grep` to print only the matching portion:

```
ping -c2 -q targethost | grep -o '[^ ]\+% packet loss'
```

#### Using awk

If the output of ping is viewed as comma-separated fields, then, as shown in your sample output, the packet loss info is in the third field.  This allows us to use awk as follows:

```
ping -c2 -q targethost | awk -F, '/packet loss/{print $3;}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep:

```
ping -c10 -f -q localhost | grep -E -o '[^[:space:]]+ packet loss'
```

Using awk:

```
ping -c10 -f -q localhost | awk -F', ' '/packet loss/ { print $3 }'
```

grep -o isn't posix, while the awk solution depends on the output format.